# How can a reference to the form created by Application.Run(new Form1()) be obtained by the Main method in the static Program class?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, reference, program-entry-point

I want to get a screen capture on the form created by `Application.Run(new Form1());`. But to do this I need to get a reference to that form.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store it in a variable:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
Application.Run(form);
```

or if you need it in a static variable instead of a local one:

```
private static Form1 form;

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    form = new Form1();
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

There's nothing magical about `Application.Run(new Form1());` - it's still just creating an instance of `Form1` and passing the reference to the `Run` method...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to store it in a variable:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
Application.Run(frm);
```

Then you can reference it.

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure your are using the namespace of that class.

```
using ProjectName.folder
```

Then create an object for the Form1() class like this.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
Application.Run(form1);
```